# How to install 32-bit libraries on Ubuntu 20.04 container images?

Tags: docker

I want to run a 32-bit program on Ubuntu 20.04, but the image I pulled from the hub is 64 bit. I have written the following dockerfile.

cat Dockerfile

```
#FROM ubuntu:latest
#FROM ubuntu:20.04-i386
FROM ubuntu:20.04
#FROM ubuntu:12.04


RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libc6:i386 -y
RUN apt-get install lib32stdc++ -y

RUN apt-get install -y debconf
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN apt-get install -y u-boot-tools      # for mkimage
RUN apt-get install -y fakeroot
RUN apt-get install -y cpio
RUN apt-get install -y gawk
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /tmp

CMD ["bash"]
```

Installing a 32-bit architecture and 32-bit standard library in it will result in the following error. What should I do?

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/18 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 3cff1c6ff37e
Step 2/18 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 655f0587955b
Step 3/18 : RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6fd7fc17eb5
Step 4/18 : RUN apt-get install libc6:i386 -y
 ---> Running in 1dd5ec986843
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install libc6:i386 -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

According to **steeldriver**'s suggestion, the issue of `libc6:i386` installation failure has been resolved, but another installation issue has occurred with the following error message:

```
Step 5/18 : RUN apt-get install lib32stdc++ -y
 ---> Running in 7c8a53cd3ae9
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-7-dbg but 7.5.0-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg but 8.4.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-9-dbg but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg-amd64-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg-amd64-cross but 8.4.0-3ubuntu1cross1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg-ppc64-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg-ppc64-cross but 8.4.0-3ubuntu1cross1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg-s390x-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg-s390x-cross but 8.4.0-3ubuntu1cross1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg-sparc64-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg-sparc64-cross but 8.4.0-3ubuntu1cross1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-10-dbg-x32-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg-x32-cross but 8.4.0-3ubuntu1cross1 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-8-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-7-dbg but 7.5.0-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6-9-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-7-dbg but 7.5.0-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-8-dbg but 8.4.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install lib32stdc++ -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: iirc you need to run `apt-get update` **after** adding the architecture

Comment: @steeldriver nice.

Comment: @steeldriver but a new error occurs,`The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install lib32stdc++ -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
`

Comment: @muru Okay, I have updated my question.

Comment: I suspect the package name you are looking for is `lib32stdc++6`, and because `lib32stdc++` doesn't have an exact match, apt is treating it as a pattern and expanding it to a bunch of other (conflicting) names

Comment: @steeldriver yes, after I changed `lib32stdc++6` to `libstdc++6:i386`, it's ok. But it was successful on `Debian12`, perhaps this is the difference between `Ubuntu` and `Debian`?